# Sum multiple columns using a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, t-sql, subquery

I'm trying to play with Oracle's DB. 
I'm trying to sum two columns from the same row and output a total on the fly. 
However, I can't seem to get it to work. Here's the code I have so far.

```
SELECT a.name , SUM(b.sequence + b.length) as total 
FROM (
  SELECT a.name, a.sequence, b.length
  FROM tbl1 a, tbl2 b
  WHERE b.sequence = a.sequence 
  AND a.loc <> -1 
  AND a.id='10201'
  ORDER BY a.location
)
```

The inner query works, but I can't seem to make the new query and the subquery work together.

Here's a sample table I'm using:

```
...[name][sequence][length]...
...['aa']['100000']['2000']...
            ...
...['za']['200000']['3001']...
```

And here's the output I'd like:

```
[name][  total ]
['aa']['102000']
            ...
['za']['203001']
```

Help much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SUM()` sums number across rows.   Instead replace it with `sequence + length`.

...or if there is the possibility of NULL values occurring in either the `sequence` or `length` columns, use: `COALESCE(sequence, 0) + COALESCE(length, 0)`.

Or, if your intention was indeed to produce a running total (i.e. aggregating the sum of all the totals and lengths for each user), add a `GROUP BY a.name` after the end of the subquery.

BTW:  you shouldn't be referencing the internal aliases used inside a subquery from outside of that subquery.   Some DB servers allow it (and I don't have convenient access to an Oracle server right now, so I can test it), but it's not really good practice.

I think what you are after is something like:

```
SELECT a.name, 
       SUM(B.sequence + B.length)    AS total
 FROM Tbl1 A
      INNER JOIN Tbl2 B
         ON B.sequence = A.sequence
WHERE A.loc <> -1
  AND A.id = 10201
      GROUP BY a.name
      ORDER BY A.location
```

Comment: Hi Curt, I do need a running total. I tried GROUP BY a.name, but it says that a.name is an invalid identifier. Even without it the sequence + length fails.

Comment: That's because you were referencing an internal alias from the subquery.   I've added a query I think will work to my answer...

Comment: Thanks. Yes that's exactly I was looking for. The subquery wasn't needed. Thanks Curt!

Answer (score 0):

Your query with the subquery fails for several reasons:

- You use the table alias `a`, but it is not defined.
- You use the table alias `b`, but it is not defined.
- You have a `sum()` in the `select` clause with unaggregated columns, but no `group by`.

In addition, you have an `order by` in the subquery which is allowed syntactically, but ignored.

Here is a better way to write the query without a subquery:

```
SELECT t1.name, (t1.sequence + t2.length) as total
FROM tbl1 t1 join
     tbl2 t2
     on t1.sequence = t2.sequence 
where t1.loc <> -1 AND t1.id = '10201'
ORDER BY t1.location;
```

Note the use of proper `join` syntax, the use of aliases that make sense, and the simple calculation at this level.

Here is a version with a subquery:

```
select name, (sequence + length) as total
from (SELECT t1.name, t1.sequence, t2.length
      FROM tbl1 t1 join
           tbl2 t2
           on t1.sequence = t2.sequence 
      where t1.loc <> -1 AND t1.id = '10201'
     ) t
ORDER BY location;
```

Note that the `order by` is going at the outer level.  And, I gave the subquery an alias.  This is not strictly required, but typically a good idea.